# Android Studio - "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)" in all of my .gwt.xml files

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, gwt, uri

I'm having a really strange issue. I'm a few days into work on a new android studio project with LibGDX, as a relative beginner to android/android studio/java/LibGDX, and I have just been trying to learn using VCS with GitHub so that I could make changes without worrying about damages.

However when I attempt to commit my project, my commit returns around 100 errors which I believe are all rooted to this:
[Error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVtxK.png)

**This occurs in every .gwt.xml file in my project**, all sharing the same link. Also, **when I normally compile and run my project, no errors occur at all.**

I have already tried searching for similar issues on this topic, all of which have returned with errors that dealt with a different URI (relating to the android APK). The solutions to those don't apply for mine either, as when I attempt to "Fetch external resource" I get the following message:

> Error while fetching http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd

Even though I am not using a proxy.

If it helps, this also occurs in my iOS folder, where the link there is:

```
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DTDs for GWT modules have long moved to gwtproject.org, but the DTDs aren't needed, they're just there to help with autocompletion in editors.

So, you can update the URL, or you can just delete the `<! DOCTYPE>` lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was wondering why ignoring the DTD fields changed it back to green and removed the compiling errors.